# RDS Server to block copy and paste contents out of my Network

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012, rds

How do I block / disable copy and paste if Users are connecting outside of my Office network in RDS Server.

Thanks,
Gulab

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to remove the ability to copy/paste...

1. Open Server Manager
2. Click "Remote Desktop Services"
3. Selected the session collection you've created under "Collections"
4. Click the drop down menu beside "Properties" and select "Edit Properties"
5. Select "Client Settings" and make sure "Clipboard" isn't selected

[Example For Visual Learners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INY6O.png)